# AndroidStudio ExternalSystemException with kotlin 0.12.213

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

#### Environment

Given I have:

1. Kotlin 0.12.213

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
       compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
   }

   buildscript {
       ext.kotlin_version = '0.12.213'
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
           classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Gradle plugin 1.2.3

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
   ```
3. Android Studio AI-141.1972460

#### Issue

When I run my android application, I get:

```
com.android.ide.common.blame.output.GradleMessage$Kind PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.kotlin, 0.12.200.Idea141.8]
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: com.android.ide.common.blame.output.GradleMessage$Kind PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.kotlin, 0.12.200.Idea141.8]
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:223)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:400)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

#### Workarounds

1. Right now the only way to run my application on AndroidStudio 1.3 Preview is to close AndroidStudio and open it again each time I want to run the app. Otherwise, subsequent runs throw the exception above.
   Invalidate cahcnes/restart, did not solve the issue.
2. Just use AndroidStudio 1.2.1.1 since the problem does not exist there.

Comment: I use Kotlin 0.11.91.4 and it works fine. Check it out :)

Comment: Me too, but I wanted to update to the last one :P

Comment: they have a bug propably :)

Comment: For me it does not work even with 0.11.91.4. Just updated AS and all the plugins and my project is not runnable anymore.

Comment: @Logain I only get that build error when using Android Studio 1.3 Preview.  With Android Studio 1.2.1.1 everything builds fine with both 0.12.200 and 0.12.213. In my gradle file I have buildToolsVersion 22.0.1 and gradle:1.2.3. In my gradle-wrapper.properties I have gradle-2.4-all.zip.

Comment: @cavega you are correct. It does not happen with AndroidStudio 1.2.1.1, I suppose 1.3 Preview is not quite usable yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in Kotlin 0.12.356. You may see the discussion in the corresponding issue: [KT-7862](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7862).